# Select Multiple Buildings using Overpass API Endpoint

Tags: reactjs, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I have the code below that shows the surface area of a building in OpenStreetMap when hovered. Here's the code:

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef, useCallback } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import * as turf from '@turf/turf';

const debounce = (func: any, wait: any) => {
  let timeout: any;

  return function executedFunction(...args) {
    const later = () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      func(...args);
    };

    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
  };
};

const MapComponent = () => {
  const [area, setArea] = useState(0);
  const [mousePosition, setMousePosition] = useState({ lat: 0, lon: 0 });
  const mapRef = useRef(null);

  // Initialize the map
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!mapRef.current) {
      const map = L.map('map').setView([59.132659900251944, 9.727169813491393], 18);
      L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);

      map.on('mousemove', (e) => {
        setMousePosition({ lat: e.latlng.lat, lon: e.latlng.lng });
      });

      mapRef.current = map;
    }
  }, []);

  const displayBuildings = useCallback((buildingData) => {
    if (buildingData && mapRef.current) {
      mapRef.current.eachLayer((layer) => {
        if (layer instanceof L.Polygon) {
          mapRef.current.removeLayer(layer);
        }
      });

      let totalArea = 0;
      const nodeMapping = {};

      buildingData.elements.forEach(element => {
        if (element.type === 'node') {
          nodeMapping[element.id] = { lat: element.lat, lon: element.lon };
        }
      });

      const features = buildingData.elements.filter(element => element.type === 'way');

      features.forEach(feature => {
        if (feature.nodes && feature.nodes.length > 0) {
          const coordinates = feature.nodes.map(nodeId => {
            const node = nodeMapping[nodeId];
            return [node.lat, node.lon]; // Lon, Lat format for Leaflet
          });

          if (coordinates.length > 0) {
            L.polygon(coordinates, { color: 'blue' }).addTo(mapRef.current);

            const geoJsonPolygon = {
              type: 'Polygon',
              coordinates: [coordinates],
            };

            totalArea += turf.area(geoJsonPolygon);
          }
        }
      });

      setArea(totalArea);
    }
  }, []);

  // Function to fetch and display building data
  const fetchAndDisplayBuildingData = useCallback(async (lat, lon) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        'https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter',
        `[out:json];
          (
            is_in(${lat},${lon});
            area._[building];
          );
          out body; >; out skel qt;`,
        {
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' }
        }
      );

      displayBuildings(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    }
  }, [displayBuildings]);

  // Debounced version of fetchAndDisplayBuildingData
  const debouncedFetchAndDisplay = useCallback(debounce(fetchAndDisplayBuildingData, 100), [
    fetchAndDisplayBuildingData
  ]);

  // Handle mouse movement
  useEffect(() => {
    if (mapRef.current) {
      mapRef.current.on('mousemove', (e) => {
        setMousePosition({ lat: e.latlng.lat, lon: e.latlng.lng });
        debouncedFetchAndDisplay(e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng);
      });
    }
  }, [debouncedFetchAndDisplay]);

  return (
    <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <p style={{ fontSize: '24px', textAlign: 'center' }}>Area: {area.toFixed(2)} square meters</p>
      <p style={{ fontSize: '24px', textAlign: 'center' }}>Mouse Position: Latitude: {mousePosition.lat.toFixed(5)}, Longitude: {mousePosition.lon.toFixed(5)}</p>
      <div id="map" style={{ height: '420px', width: '420px' }}></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MapComponent;
```

I want it to be selectable on click and have that value then saved. Multiple buildings need to be saved. In addition, is there a way to get the roof angle data as well?

I need the angle data as I need to calculate the true area of the roof of a building, not just the space it occupies on a 2D map. This specific true area value needs to then be saved.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a way to get the roof angle data as well? No, I can't find the solution. I check Overpass documentation, There are no angle of building or roof data.

This demo can handle Multiple buildings save data by mouse click over the build area.

Save format example

```
Area: 197.70, Latitude: 59.13330, Longitude: 9.72721, Tags: {"building":"house","ref:bygningsnr":"300001805"}
```

Adding feature Tags and shows all of saved build information by Clicking.

```
  const handleMouseClick = () => {
    const newDataItem = {
      area: area.toFixed(2),
      geo_location: {
        lat: mousePosition.lat.toFixed(5),
        longitude: mousePosition.lon.toFixed(5)
      },
      tags: buildingTag
    };

    setDataToSave([...dataToSave, newDataItem]);
  };
```

Call this call back function from map's `<div>` tag by `onClick()` event.

```html
<div id="map" style={{ height: '800px', width: '100%', maxWidth: '1000px' }} onClick={handleMouseClick}></div>
```

Getting Tags information from Overpass API

```
if (element.type === 'way' && element.tags) {
   setBuildingTag(JSON.stringify(element.tags));
}
```

Data source from `Overpass`

```json
{
  "type": "way",
  "id": 944874632,
  "nodes": [
    8747572457,
    8747572456,
    8747572455,
    8747572454,
    8747572453,
    8747557628,
    8747557629,
    8747572452,
    8747572451,
    8747572457
  ],
  "tags": {
    "building": "house",
    "building:levels": "2",
    "ref:bygningsnr": "22480235"
  }
}
```

##### Demo code

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, useCallback } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import * as turf from '@turf/turf';

const debounce = (func, wait) => {
  let timeout;

  return function executedFunction(...args) {
    const later = () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      func(...args);
    };

    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
  };
};

const MapComponent = () => {
  const [area, setArea] = useState(0);
  const [mousePosition, setMousePosition] = useState({ lat: 0, lon: 0 });
  const [dataToSave, setDataToSave] = useState([]);
  const [buildingTag, setBuildingTag] = useState("");
  const mapRef = useRef(null);

  // Initialize the map
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!mapRef.current) {
      const map = L.map('map').setView([59.132659900251944, 9.727169813491393], 18);
      L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
      }).addTo(map);

      map.on('mousemove', (e) => {
        setMousePosition({ lat: e.latlng.lat, lon: e.latlng.lng });
      });

      mapRef.current = map;
    }
  }, []);

  const displayBuildings = useCallback((buildingData) => {
    if (buildingData && mapRef.current) {
      mapRef.current.eachLayer((layer) => {
        if (layer instanceof L.Polygon) {
          mapRef.current.removeLayer(layer);
        }
      });

      let totalArea = 0;
      const nodeMapping = {};

      buildingData.elements.forEach(element => {
        if (element.type === 'node') {
          nodeMapping[element.id] = { lat: element.lat, lon: element.lon };
        }
        if (element.type === 'way' && element.tags) {
          setBuildingTag(JSON.stringify(element.tags));
        }
      });

      const features = buildingData.elements.filter(element => element.type === 'way');

      features.forEach(feature => {
        if (feature.nodes && feature.nodes.length > 0) {
          const coordinates = feature.nodes.map(nodeId => {
            const node = nodeMapping[nodeId];
            return [node.lat, node.lon]; // Lon, Lat format for Leaflet
          });

          if (coordinates.length > 0) {
            L.polygon(coordinates, { color: 'blue' }).addTo(mapRef.current);

            const geoJsonPolygon = {
              type: 'Polygon',
              coordinates: [coordinates],
            };

            totalArea += turf.area(geoJsonPolygon);
          }
        }
      });

      setArea(totalArea);
    }
  }, []);

  // Function to fetch and display building data
  const fetchAndDisplayBuildingData = useCallback(async (lat, lon) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        'https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter',
        `[out:json];
          (
            is_in(${lat},${lon});
            area._[building];
          );
          out body; >; out skel qt;`,
        {
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' }
        }
      );

      displayBuildings(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    }
  }, [displayBuildings]);

  const handleMouseClick = () => {
    const newDataItem = {
      area: area.toFixed(2),
      geo_location: {
        lat: mousePosition.lat.toFixed(5),
        longitude: mousePosition.lon.toFixed(5)
      },
      tags: buildingTag
    };

    setDataToSave([...dataToSave, newDataItem]);
  };

  const handleClearData = () => {
    setDataToSave([]);
  };

  // Debounced version of fetchAndDisplayBuildingData
  const debouncedFetchAndDisplay = useCallback(debounce(fetchAndDisplayBuildingData, 100), [
    fetchAndDisplayBuildingData
  ]);

  // Handle mouse movement
  useEffect(() => {
    if (mapRef.current) {
      mapRef.current.on('mousemove', (e) => {
        setMousePosition({ lat: e.latlng.lat, lon: e.latlng.lng });
        debouncedFetchAndDisplay(e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng);
      });
    }
  }, [debouncedFetchAndDisplay]);

  return (
    <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <p style={{ fontSize: '24px', textAlign: 'center' }}>Area: {area.toFixed(2)} square meters</p>
      <p style={{ fontSize: '24px', textAlign: 'center' }}>Mouse Position: Latitude: {mousePosition.lat.toFixed(5)}, Longitude: {mousePosition.lon.toFixed(5)}</p>
      <p style={{ fontSize: '24px', textAlign: 'center' }}>Tag: {buildingTag}</p>
      <div id="map" style={{ height: '800px', width: '100%', maxWidth: '1000px' }} onClick={handleMouseClick}></div>
      <button onClick={handleClearData}>Clear data</button>
      <div style={{ maxHeight: '400px', overflowY: 'auto' }}>
        <h2>Saved Data</h2>
        <ul>
          {dataToSave.map((data, index) => (
            <li key={index}>
              Area: {data.area}, Latitude: {data.geo_location.lat}, Longitude: {data.geo_location.longitude}, Tags: {data.tags}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MapComponent;
```

##### Result

[image]

Comment: If i decide to make the coordinates dynamic, as in being fed in from another function I have where the user inputs an address, and using an API I get the coordinates from the address. How can I do this? And can the map refresh when the input changes?

Comment: Convert from geolocation(latitude, longitude) to mail address limited service from Nomination(https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org) by API call rate control and number of call. It may be using paid google API service. I try it, can you make new question. I don't fully understand map refresh. This map component has no persistence data. If refreshes screen, the saved data will be lost. You should be copy from saved to data by copy/paste of data to save like notepad before refreshing. It is limited to this component.

Comment: This is example to get mail address by nomicatim service. Example: `GET https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=59.132659900251944, 9.727169813491393&polygon_geojson=1&format=json`   , the mail address will response, like this : `54, Kvestadåsen, Grønsholt, Porsgrunn, Vestfold og Telemark, 3948, Norge`. But if call a couple of time, the serve will make to response time out and not respond a day.

Comment: I think you didn't understand me correctly, I wasn't looking for email address, but for a house address. For example, the user inputs their house address, and then using an API i get the coordinates. This part is already done, but how do I adjust the code you posted in order to accept dynamic coords?

Comment: Also, is it possible to keep the selected buildings highlighted after the user clicks on them? Even after I move the mouse away?

Comment: it means house address -> geo location(lat, lon) -> area calculation?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean

Comment: OK, two new features, User enter house address(or click on the map) can add save data  and keep adding the blue polygon until clear data. Can you confirm it and make new question. It is new features. May be I can start in tonight.

Comment: Just posted a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77942348/dynamically-update-overpass-api-map